# Why is my hard drive mounted on /boot?

Tags: mount

I was doing an update and it said that the drive was full.

Here is df -h:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
                       78G  2.7G   72G   4% /
none                  242M  184K  242M   1% /dev
none                  247M     0  247M   0% /dev/shm
none                  247M   48K  247M   1% /var/run
none                  247M     0  247M   0% /var/lock
none                  247M     0  247M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1             228M  225M     0 100% /boot
```

Here is fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 85.9 GB, 85899345920 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 10443 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00035711

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          32      249855   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              32        1045     8136705    5  Extended
/dev/sda3            1045       10444    75498496   83  Linux
/dev/sda5              32        1045     8136704   8e  Linux LVM
```

Here is mount:

```
/dev/mapper/sprintsftp-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
```

Here is /etc/fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/mapper/machine-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=08ddfaa4-0da2-405e-95b2-b228a95dc761 /boot           ext2    defaults     $
/dev/mapper/machine-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

How can I fix /dev/sda1 being mounted on /boot?

Comment: Can you please post your `/etc/fstab`? i.e. `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: @reverendj1 - updated the original post with fstab.

Comment: You use LVM, so this setup is normal. Just delete old kernels to free space on `/boot`, and everything will work fine

Comment: @MestreLion - The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  linux-image-server: Depends: linux-image-2.6.32-43-server but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: @divided: what command you issued? Do you know how to delete old kernels?

Comment: @MestreLion - I've never done it before but I was following a guide and issued `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.32-21-server`

Comment: @divided: see my answer below, and upvote and/or accept it if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, perhaps your only issue a full `/boot` partition. Since you're using LVM, the output you posted in fstab, mount, etc look fine.

And the best way to free space in `/boot` is to remove old kernel versions. If you're new to this, I suggest using Software Center:

- Search for "linux-image". Take a note on the most recent one (your current kernel), and delete all the previous ones. Only remove the ones with version numbers like `linux-image-3.2.0-xx-server`, do *not* delete the "main" `linux-image-server` or `linux-image`. Be sure to keep your current version number.
- Do the same with "linux-headers"

You're good to go!

Also, as a side-note... you may reconsider administering an Ubuntu Server if you still need tutorials for managing disk space and kernel versions. Have you tried Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have two issues.

1. Your /boot partition is full - this happens if you update the kernel enough times and don't remove the old ones. It's always a good idea to keep at least one old kernel in case you find something that doesn't work with an updated one, but you don't need more than three. Do you boot with GRUB? How many kernel options do you get?
2. There is no entry for your root (i.e. the top entry, "/") filesystem location. It shows that you have an 80GB partition but it doesn't show a mount point. Here's mine:

df  -h:

```
kevin@nx-6325:# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5              20G  9.6G  8.8G  53% /
none                  434M  280K  434M   1% /dev
none                  438M  252K  438M   1% /dev/shm
none                  438M  208K  438M   1% /var/run
none                  438M     0  438M   0% /var/lock
none                  438M     0  438M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda2             244M  197M   35M  86% /boot
kevin@nx-6325:#
```

As you can see, my root filesystem is mounted on /dev/sda5. Also note that my /boot has 197M used - that's with 4 kernels as I've been too lazy to delete the old ones!

Please post the output of

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

and also

```
mount
```

If you need help deleting old kernels post back or Google it - it's very easy to do.

EDIT:
As stated by MestreLion, it looks like your only issue is a full /boot partition which is preventing you from upgrading the kernel. To remove all but the two latest, I use the script below. The original is here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1634760&page=2 and all I've done is add a couple of lines so that you are advised what will be kept and what will be deleted before it starts (and you also have the option to abort if you wish). I have just run it now, to delete the three oldest out of five kernels and it ran fine.

Copy all the text below and save it in your home directory as purge-kernel.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get a list of the kernels that are installed.
kernelList=$(cd /;ls boot/vmlinuz*)
# Make a list of the kernels to keep. These are the kernels linked to by /vmlinuz,
# /vmlinuz.old, and the currently running kernel.
keepList="$(readlink -q /vmlinuz) $(readlink -q /vmlinuz.old) boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)"
# Change the list of file names to list of package names.
kernelPkg=$(sed 's@boot/vmlinuz-@linux-image-@g' <<<$kernelList)
keepPkg=$(sed 's@boot/vmlinuz-@linux-image-@g' <<<$keepList)
# Create a list of packages to purge. This is the list of installed kernels with the kernels
# to keep removed.
purgePkg=${kernelPkg}
for keep in $keepPkg
do
    eval purgePkg=\${purgePkg/$keep}
done
purgePkg=$(echo $purgePkg)  # Remove extra white space
echo -ne "\nWill keep the following kernels: $keepPkg\n\n"
echo -ne "Will remove the following kernels: $purgePkg\n\n"
read -p "Press enter to continue, <Ctrl>-C to abort..."
# If there are any kernels to remove then purge them and update grub;
if [ -n "${purgePkg}" ]
then
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
chmod +x $tmpfile
echo "dpkg --purge ${purgePkg};update-grub"
echo "dpkg --purge ${purgePkg};update-grub" > $tmpfile
sudo -s $tmpfile
sleep 1  # following 'rm' fails otherwise.
rm -f $tmpfile
else
echo "No kernels to purge."
fi
exit
```

Make it executable by running

```
chmod +x purge-kernel.sh
```

Run it by opening a terminal in your home directory with:

```
./purge-kernel.sh
```

You will be prompted for your password as the script requires root privileges.

Comment: I updated the original post with the info you requested.